# How to display the Data of CKEditor in react ( videos and images )

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I am working on Blog Appliction in MERN an I have used CKEditor to enter the description in CKeditor from admin panel the data of CKEditor is storing in HTML tags and currently i am using
`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`  to ignore the tags of html and show the data in just

tag but i want to show the data with the exact tags as it was enter  by CKEditor

**For example**

like if Admin add the unorder list or orderlist it should be disply on frontend but currently it is just showing ther data on new line without bulets

what showing now

Heading
A
B
C
D

What is was expecting

Heading

1. A
2. B
3. C
4. D